# How to stop a user form adding forms to a field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a form that allows a user to update their profile information, but I would like to prevent some information from being changed. I also would like to keep my controller code very simple. In the update action of my Users Controller, I have the following code:

```
def update
  @user = Users.find params[:id]

  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:notice] = 'Update successful.'
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  else
    render :action => :edit
  end
end
```

This is very clean and simple, and I like that. What I don't like, however, is that a user can add a field to the form, with the same name as an attribute, and use it to modify forbidden attributes. Is there a simple way to do this, or do I need to devise a way to do this myself?

One method I was considering was to generate a hash value, using a [hash-based message authentication code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyed-hash_message_authentication_code), of all the form's element names. This message access code would be a hidden value in the form. Then, once the form is submitted, I would calculate the message access code (MAC) again using the names of the parameter Hash's keys. If the two MACs are different, or if the first MAC is missing from the parameter Hash, I would throw an error. I would rather not spend the time implementing this if there was already and easy solution out there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your model you can use [attr_protected](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M000350) or [attr_accessible](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M000351) to blacklist or whitelist attributes when being set via mass assignment (like when a form is submitted).

Comment: I posted this above too. I know about attr_accessible and attr_protected, but I feel they add unneeded complexity to my app. For instance, Users should not be able to modify their username, but an Admin should be able to modify everyone's user name. It would seem cumbersome to have something like `@user.update_attribute(:login, params[:login] if current_user.role? :admin` Multiple lines of this type of code would need to go into all my controllers. Another bad thing is that a lot of that logic is already defined in my CanCan ability file, so there will be a fair amount of code duplication.

Comment: What about - http://enlightsolutions.com/articles/whats-new-in-edge-scoped-mass-assignment-in-rails-3-1

Answer (score 1):

Rails will prevent mass assignment if you use `attr_protected :protectedcolumn` (blacklist) or `attr_accessible :safecolumn` (whitelist) within your model. More information on this topic can be found in the [Ruby on Rails Security Guide (Section 6.1)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment)

Comment: I know about attr_accessible and attr_protected, but I feel they add unneeded complexity to my app. For instance, Users should not be able to modify their username, but an Admin should be able to modify everyone's username. It would seem cumbersome to have something like `@user.update_attribute(:login, params[:login] if current_user.role? :admin` Multiple lines of this type of code would need to go into all my controllers. Another bad thing is that a lot of that logic is already defined in my CanCan ability file, so there will be a fair amount of code duplication.